# Antiderivative of $e^{-|x|}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Splitting the function into the negative and positive parts of the domain of $x$ gives
$$
e^{-|x|}=
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
&e^x, &x ≤ 0 \\ 
&e^{-x}, &x > 0, 
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$
which is trivial to integrate.

Now, the problem is, the answer given in our professor's quiz, and by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20e%5E%28-abs%28x%29%29), is:

$$
\int e^{-|x|}\ dx=
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
&e^x + c, &x ≤ 0 \\ 
-&e^{-x} + 2 + c, &x > 0 \\ 
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$

I have absolutely no idea where the $+2$ term could come from.

Comment: There shouldn't be a $-$ sign in the definition of $e^{-|x|}$: for negative $x$ it's equal to $e^{-x}$.

Comment: The antiderivative given by Wolfram in your link is not what you say it is. However the extra $2$ has no effect anyway.

Comment: The antiderivative is continuous at 0, so $1+C_1=-1+C_2$ and $ C_2=C_1+2$

Comment: @coffeemath weird. [This](https://ibb.co/FJBsTjJ) is the result I get on mobile app.

Comment: Your original specification (i.e. interpretation) of $e^{-|x|}$ is accurate for $x \leq 0$ but **wrong** for $x > 0$.  For $x > 0, ~ e^{-|x|} = e^{-x},~$ **rather than** $~-e^{-x}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $+2$ is added so that the derivative is continuous at $x = 0$.

This has the advantage that the derivative at $x = 0$ also exists and is equal to $1$.

Comment: It might also be mentioned that  $ \ e^{−|x|} \ $  is a continuous even function, so its anti-derivative should have odd symmetry or at least have something resembling that. (Setting  $ \ c = -1 \ $ in both branches gives the anti-derivative strictly odd symmetry and the horizontal asymptotes become $ \ y = −1 \ $ and $ \ y = 1 \   . $  The continuous anti-derivative has a "sigmoid" curve.)

Answer (score 3):

If that $2$ was not there, that function would not even be continuous, and so it would not be differentiable.